# Newbie in RDF need to find subject, verb, object

Tags: rdf

I have a lesson, where they asked me to find the subject,verb and object.
I can find most of them bug I bug On 1 , where they didn't show us , how to find these :
here's my code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" 
     xmlns:pcv="http://prismstandard.org/namespaces/pcv/1.0/" 
     xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">

<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://wanderlust.com/2000/08/Corfu.jpg"> 
<dc:identifier rdf:resource="http://wanderlust.com/content/2357845" /> 
<dc:creator> 
<pcv:Descriptor rdf:about="http://wanderlust.com/emp3845"> 
<pcv:label>John Peterson </pcv:label> 
</pcv:Descriptor> 
</dc:creator> 
<dc:coverage> 
<pcv:Descriptor 
rdf:about="http://prismstandard.org/vocabs/ISO-3166/GR"> 
<pcv:label xml:lang="en">Greece</pcv:label>
<pcv:label xml:lang="fr">Grece</pcv:label> 
</pcv:Descriptor> 
</dc:coverage> 
</rdf:Description> 
</rdf:RDF>
```

for this line :Greece
I think that :
-the subject is : http://wanderlust.com/emp3845
-the verb is : http://prismstandard.org/namespaces/pcv/1.0/label
-the object is : "Greece"

**But what can I do with the xml:lang="en" ??**
Can I find an object for this ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, there are two objects: `"Greece"@en` and `"Grece"@fr`. It becomes visible if you use human-oriented representation of RDF such as [Turtle](http://www.w3.org/TR/turtle/):

```
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix pcv: <http://prismstandard.org/namespaces/pcv/1.0/> .
@prefix dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/> .

<http://prismstandard.org/vocabs/ISO-3166/GR>
    pcv:label "Grece"@fr, "Greece"@en ;
    a pcv:Descriptor .

<http://wanderlust.com/2000/08/Corfu.jpg>
    dc:coverage <http://prismstandard.org/vocabs/ISO-3166/GR> ;
    dc:creator <http://wanderlust.com/emp3845> ;
    dc:identifier <http://wanderlust.com/content/2357845> .

<http://wanderlust.com/emp3845>
    pcv:label "John Peterson " ;
    a pcv:Descriptor .
```

So, what we see here is, that there are 3 subjects. First has 2 "verbs" (or "predicates") and one of those has 2 "objects"

Comment: I re-read your post, and I appreciate your response. I assume you Downvoted mine, which without an explanation, isn't very SO friendly.  I think your question does a nice job of clarifying this, but mine also addresses the confusion, and should not have been downvoted.  If yours is superior, you will typically be rewarded by the community.

Answer (score -1):

RDF is implemented within the confines of the XML specification.  The `xml:lang=` is a feature of the xml specification that allows the content author to specify the language of the element as an attribute.  Attributes are the elements that appear within the start and end `<..>` of a start tag for an element, and serve to refine or configure the tag.  It is not part of RDF specifically, and isn't a subject, verb or object.

This has some specific examples and an explanation:

https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-when-xmllang.en

Comment: Downvoted, with no explanation, and this answer directly addressed the question:  "But what can I do with the xml:lang="en" ?? Can I find an object for this ?"